# Error uploading to iOS App Store: ERROR ITMS-9000 "This bundle is invalid"

Tags: ios, app-store, xcode5, marmalade, application-loader

When we try to upload a new version of our app to Apple's App Store we get the following error in Application Loader:

```
ERROR ITMS-9000: "This bundle is invalid. New apps and app updates submitted to the App Store
must be built with public (GM) versions of Xcode 5 and iOS 7 SDK. Do not submit apps built with
beta software." at SoftwareAssets/SoftwareAsset (MZItmspSoftwareAssetPackage)
```

***We are already building with the latest available version of Xcode, 5.1.1 (downloaded from the Mac App Store) and v7.1 of the iOS SDK (which came with Xcode 5.1.1).***

Our app is built with Marmalade 7.2.1. We've tried rebuilding all of the EDK extensions and static libraries that our app uses.

What could be going wrong? Is there anything more anyone else can tell us about the error to help us track it down?

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue and we don't use Marmalade.

Comment: @MrRogers Are you packaging your app directly with Xcode, or using another system similar to Marmalade? I notice that Oxygene also seems to require that these settings be added manually to an `Info.plist`.

Comment: I was using the Application Uploader app provided by Apple.

Comment: @MrRogers How are you *creating* the package you upload, though? If you're using tools that create the .ipa outside of Xcode (such as Marmalade, or Oxygene) then the problem may be caused by values in the Info.plist that is included in the final .ipa, as it was for me.

Comment: Rich sorry! I figured out the reason for my problem and totally spaced it for this discussion.  :( The problem was that I got so caught up by the beta software portion of the message that I didn't notice that our build machine had Xcode 5.1 instead of Xcode 5.1.1 which was invalid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Xcode creates an `.ipa` package, it adds a number of elements to your project's Info.plist.

As our package is created with Marmalade's deployment tool, these elements need to be manually included in an `Info.plist` that is copied directly (with a much smaller amount of pre-processing) into the final `.ipa`.

Marmalade includes a standard `Info.plist` file within its installation for this purpose. However, you can override this, and we had done so by making a copy of their file, and updating it with changes we needed to make.

A later version of Marmalade made some changes to this file, and we hadn't copied these over into our file, and the difference is apparently what was causing the App Store to think that the App was built with an earlier version of Xcode than the version actually used.

The values which differed were `DTSDKName`, `DTSDKBuild`, `DTXCode`, `DTXcodeBuild`, `DTPlatformBuild`, and `DTCompiler`.

Answer (score 5):

```
Starting May 15, 2014, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with Xcode 5.1.1
```

You have to update your xcode.

Comment: If that had been the problem, then the error message would have sufficed to solve it! As stated in the question, though, we were already using the latest version of Xcode, 5.1.1. The problem was that the values in our `Info.plist` did not reflect the version of Xcode we were using.

Answer (score 0):

Just clean all the things.

Check the developer/distribution certificate and mobile provision profile properly created, if not then revoke them from developer account and create all new one.

Remove all profiles from /Users/yourSystemName/Library/MobileDevice/Provisioning Profiles

Now, Export all certificates and keys from your keychain and Save them as backup for using them again.

Now install your developer/Distribution certificate first and install provisioning profile. And upload your application. This is tested way and should resolve your issue. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, but as I described in [my own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23686061/328936), the problem was caused by some out-of-date values in the `Info.plist`.